# Connection between Unix processes, how to get full name and root directory for a given username

Tags: linux, unix, pipe

I need to write a script which should have an username as a parameter. Using the username give i have to search and print out its full name and its root directory. I have to use "pipe".

I did a little research on Google, but didn't find anything useful, not even how this script should look like using pipe. The only thing i found it is this:

```
homedir=$( getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f6 )
```

it does half of what i want, but still not what i'm looking for.

e.g: I'm the client, i want to find out this informations for Sebi and i need the server to return:

```
FullName: Sebi CN
Root Directory: System32
```

NOTE: I'm working on a virtual machine, using ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

The root directory can be found in the file `/etc/passwd`.

```
grep "username" /etc/passwd
```

gives the corresponding line.